# How add videos and subtitles Through the Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

The subtitle should go into the textarea where it shows body as a textarea and then add into the video because I'm working on the textarea

```
html
 <video id="video-player" controls autoplay pause volume fullscreen></video>
    </div>
<br>
    <div id="fileLoadDiv">
      <input id="fileInput" type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;" />
      <input id="fileLoadButton" type="button" value="Load Video File" onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click()" />
```

```
JavaScript
const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');

function loadFile(event){
    videoPlayer.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: what's your problem? I am unsure of what you need help with.

Comment: i need video plyer like this picture and The subtitle should go into the textarea where it shows body as a textarea and then add into the video because I'm working on the textarea